how can i make sure that android app i create using android studio is going to work on all android devices(I am testing app on android 10 to 14)
I have created android app in android studio in September 2024 for android 14 devices. The problem is The app is working perfectly on Samsung M35(android 14) but not on Samsung A53(android 14). For eg when I add some items on A53 it is showing them twice. But it show them once. I am displaying them in recyclerview

You can't.  Particularly not without defining "all" and what the app does.  For example, how old of devices do you want to support?  If you want to support any Android device ever made you can, but it will take a lot of effort and there's a lot of features you can't use.  Come back with a narrower definition of what you want.

By "all" I meant android 10 to 14 devices.The app is basic it has a button on mainactivity.java which open mycustomcamera.java from where we can capture photos and videos. Captured photos and videos will be displayed to mainactivity.java 's recyclerview. Mainactivity.java has upload button by pressing it upload capture media to server. On Samsung A53 it is showing each item twice instead of once

You still run into the problem of you can't really prove a negative.  You can't prove that there's no device where it doesn't work.  A device could have a bad version of Android and not patched it, or have OEM extentions to the kernel that break something.  Your best bet is to test manually on devices that report an error.  There are services like AWS device farm which allow you to test on devices you don't physically own remotely.
